# How to find single letter words with gedit

Tags: search, gedit, letter

I have a very long text with thousands of words and I'm using gedit in order to read it; some of the words are formed by just one letter (for example the letter "d"); when I use the word searcher by typing `ctrl+f` the search box pops up; when I type the letter that I am looking for I get all the words that contain that letter while I would like to see only those words formed just by the single one.
How can I get only the words formed by the single letter I typed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume that all the words are separated by space(" "),
So instead of searching just the letter e.g. **"d"**, try to search **" d "** , It should point out the words formed by just one letter.